# User roles schema design comparison

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm learning how to design a DB structure for assigning users permission to access certain pages

- if the user is an admin that user would have access to crud operations
- if the user is an editor that user would have access to only edit
- user can have custom permission then access it would vary depending on the config

I have two schema designs and both seems good, one requires simple queries and the other can hold more description about each role and permission.

**Design 1**

[image]

role id is stored in a table called `user` and i will need to lookup `role_has_permission` table get all the permission ids then lookup `permission` table to get the `permission_name` column. comparatively longer query with more data being fetched, but i can have `description` column in `permission` table

**Design 2**

[image]

role id stored in table user, i can simply make a single query and check for permission. eg: `role.canEdit` is set to true user is allowed to edit. smaller and faster query.

why cant i go with the second design? and why do many articles go with the first design?

Comment: json complicated to update, and the first is normalized, without redundancies

Answer (score 1):

Design 1 lets you add permissions dynamically without changing the software. If you need a new permission, say `can order lunch for entire team`, you just add a record in the `permission` table and as many in the `role_has_permission` as needed, and you're done. In design 2 you'd have to add an operation `canOrderLunchForEntireTeam`. So design 1 is more flexible.

However, the flexibility of design 1 has a price. It's not enough to define and assign these permissions, but the software shall probably also check them when a function is performed. Adding a function for ordering lunch is a software change anyway, so adding an attribute to your design 2 class might be tolerable. The generic way of defining permissions in design 1 will therefore only pay out if you implement a similarly generic way of applying them.